# Rails 4: fields_for in fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for, fields-for, nested-form-for

I am learning RoR and i am trying to find how to set a fields_for in another one with has_one models like this:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :father
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :father
end

class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :child
    belongs_to :grandfather
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :grandfather
end


class Grandfather < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :father
end
```

I used Nested Model Form Part 1 on Railscasts to get these:
In children_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @child = Child.new
    father=@child.build_father
    father.build_grandfather
  end

def child_params
      params.require(:child).permit(:name, father_attributes:[:name], grandfather_attributes:[:name])
    end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for(@child) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  mother:<br>
  <%= f.fields_for :father do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.label :name %>
    <%= ff.text_field :name %><br>
      grand mother:<br>
      <%= f.fields_for :grandfather do |fff| %>
        <%= fff.label :name %>
        <%= fff.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to retrieve the datas with:

```
<%= child.father.name %>
<%= child.father.grandfather.name %>
```

but the grandfather's name won't work.
I cannot find the mistake(s)...anyone to help on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try switching:

```
<%= f.fields_for :grandfather do |fff| %>
```

to:

```
<%= ff.fields_for :grandfather do |fff| %>
```

And switching:

```
params.require(:child).permit(:name, father_attributes:[:name], grandfather_attributes:[:name])
```

To:

```
params.require(:child).permit(:name, father_attributes:[:name, grandfather_attributes:[:name]])
```